# How to create space when create multi column with bootstrap 4.2

Tags: bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap 4.2

I have  four columns but I tried space in margin But I see sticking together.

[image]

I use class `col, col-sm-3, card` , but I did not succeed

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="bg-primary text-center p-5 col bg">
        <a class="text-white" href="">Car</a>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-info text-center p-5 col bg">
        <a class="text-white" href="">House</a>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-danger text-center p-5 col bg">
        <a class="text-white" href="">Mobile</a>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-warning text-center p-5 col bg">
        <a class="text-white" href="#">Laptop</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making a custom class and adding `margin-right: 10px;` as a CSS rule for it?

Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="bg-primary custom text-center p-5 col bg">
        <a class="text-white" href="">Car</a>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-info custom text-center p-5 col bg">
        <a class="text-white" href="">House</a>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-danger custom text-center p-5 col bg">
        <a class="text-white" href="">Mobile</a>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-warning custom text-center p-5 col bg">
        <a class="text-white" href="#">Laptop</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in your CSS file:

```
.custom {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on desktop it should shows a gap between each column

```
<div class="row">
<div class="bg-primary col-md-3 text-center p-5 bg">
    <a class="text-white" href="">Car</a>
</div>
<div class="bg-info col-md-3 text-center p-5 bg">
    <a class="text-white" href="">House</a>
</div>
<div class="bg-danger col-md-3  text-center p-5 bg">
    <a class="text-white" href="">Mobile</a>
</div>
<div class="bg-warning col-md-3  text-center p-5 bg">
    <a class="text-white" href="#">Laptop</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.